# Form Validation With Record Saved Message

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly, my apologies, I'm relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery, so perhaps this is a really stupid question.

Using these tutorials [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-sleek-ajax-signup-form/) and [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test.php) page to allow users to add records to a MySQL database but I'm having a little difficulty with the form 'validation' and jQuery 'submission' message.

If use select the above link, then once the page has loaded, select 'Save', you'll see that the correct field validation is activated, but despite being validation errors, the 'Location saved' message appears at the bottom of the page, and the page refreshes saving the record to the database.

Obviously this is not supposed to happen, but I'm having great difficulty in joining the 'validation' and 'submission' message. Independently they work fine, but as you can see, once together they don't.

The code below deals with the 'Save Record' and refresh of the page

**UPDATE - Working Solution Below**

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#addlocation").validationEngine();
            $("#addlocation").bind("jqv.field.result", function(event, field, errorFound, prompText){ console.log(errorFound) })
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addlocation').submit(function(){

        //check the form is not currently submitting
        if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){

            //setup variables
            var form = $(this),
                formData = form.serialize(),
                formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
                responseMsg = $('#saverecordresponse');

            //add status data to form
            form.data('formstatus','submitting');

            //show response message - waiting
            responseMsg.hide()
                       .addClass('response-waiting')
                       .text('Please Wait...')
                       .fadeIn(200);

            //send data to server for validation
            $.ajax({
                url: formUrl,
                type: formMethod,
                data: formData,
                success:function(data){

                    //setup variables
                    var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                        klass = '';

                    //response conditional
                    switch(responseData.status){
                        case 'error':
                            klass = 'response-error';
                        break;
                        case 'success':
                            klass = 'response-success';
                        break;  
                    }

                    //show reponse message
                    responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                               .addClass(klass)
                               .text(responseData.message)
                               .fadeIn(200,function(){
                                   //set timeout to hide response message
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                       responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                           $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                           form.data('formstatus','idle');
                                       });
                                   },3000)
                                });
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        //prevent form from submitting
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is the 'saverecord.php' script which is called upon selecting the 'Save' button.

```
<?php


    //sanitize data
    $userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);   
    $locationname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['locationname']);   
    $returnedaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['returnedaddress']); 

    //validate email address - check if input was empty
    if(empty($locationname)){
        $status = "error";
        $message = "You didn't enter a name for this location!";
    }
    else if(!preg_match('/^$|^[A-Za-z0-9 _.,]{5,35}$/', $locationname)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
            $status = "error";
            $message = "You have entered an invalid Location Name!";
    }

    else{
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (userid, locationname, returnedaddress) VALUES ('$userid', '$locationname', '$returnedaddress')");  
            if($query){ //if insert is successful
                $status = "success";
                $message = "Location Saved!";   
            }
            else { //if insert fails
                $status = "error";
                $message = "I'm sorry, there has been a technical error! Please try again. If problems persist please contact Map My Finds support.";   
            }

    }

    //return json response
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
?>
```

I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: `!==` isn't correct , try `!=`

Comment: Hi @Tornike thank you very much for replying to my post. I have made the change you suggested, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. Kind regards

Comment: It seems you've another error in script, what it gets in console.log ? or if error in php what exactly error occurs ?

Comment: Hi @Tornike, thank you for your reply. I've run through JavaScript Console and unfortunately there are no errors being returned. Kind regards

Comment: @Tornike `!==` is correct as well [though not needed here], it just [compares value and type](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Comment: @IRHM in the [demo](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/addlocation.php) where is save button?

Comment: Hi @KundanSinghChouhan, thank you for replying to my post. The 'Save' button is at the bottom of the page. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM you provided this link http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/addlocation.php and its redirects to http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/index.php and i am not getting any save button there. here is a login secion only

Comment: Hi @KundanSinghChouhan, could you possibly try it again please? Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, same thing happened are you getting the save button at your side?

Comment: Hi @KundanSinghChouhan, thank your for this. This is a little strange as the link works fine at my end. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM its such a strange issue :)

Comment: Hi @KundanSinghChouhan, yes I see where the problem is. My sincere apologies. I'll have to work at this and try to resolve the issue. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @KundanSinghChouhan, if you could possibly try it now, everything should be working fine. Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of working on this, I now have a working solution by using the example [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-sleek-ajax-signup-form/) which I've added to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
if($.validationEngine.submitForm(this,settings) == true) {return false;}
```

somewhere before your $.ajax line

Comment: Hi @khartnett, thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this. I did try your line of code, but unfortunately the 'jQuery' message hung on 'Please Wait' and wouldn't submit the form. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @IRHM, I think that Kundan Singh Chouhan had you heading in the right direction. I noticed two syntax errors when running test.php. This could contribute to your problems. They are both for Unexpected token } at lines 102 and 302

Answer (score 1):

IRHM, check that the form is validate before submit in your event i.e.

```
$('#addlocation').submit(function(){
    if($(this).validate()){
       // put your all existing content here.
    }  
});
```

To prevent submitting the form after ajax put return false at the end of above script in if block i.e.

```
if($(this).validate()){
    // put your all existing content here.
    return false;
}
```

I guess the problem is occurring due to validation engine, so in that case to prevent form to submit try to use as follows:

```
$('#addlocation').submit(function(evt){
    if($(this).validate()){
       evt.preventDefault();
       // put your all existing content here.
    }  
});
```

If the above code doesn't work then include `onValidationComplete` event with `validationEngine` and put you all existing stuff of **if($(this).validate())** block in that i.e.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
   jQuery("#addlocation").validationEngine({ onValidationComplete: function(){ 

        //setup variables

        //add status data to form

        //show response message - waiting

        //send data to server for validation

        return false; 
      }
    });
});
```

Good Luck

Comment: Hi @KundanSinghChouhan, thank you very much for this. The fields are correctly validated and the 'Save' function only works once this takes place. However, instead of the jQuery 'Location Saved' message appearing at the bottom of the page on button click, the browser open a new window displaying this message:
{"status":"success","message":"Location Saved!"}
I'm sorry to trouble you with this again, but I just wondered whether you could possibly look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong. The test page is still set up which illustrates the problem. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM again the "addlocation.php" page redirects to "index.php" and i am unable to see that page.

Comment: Hi @Kundan Singh Chouhan. My apologies, I've had to change the page name. If you use this as the address, it should be fine www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test.php. Once again many thanks for your help and kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM, it is because you have specified the action in the form so its re-submit page again after ajax call. To prevent this just put the return false after the ajax success or error, This will fix the issue :)

Comment: Hi @Kundan Singh Chouhan, thank you for your continued help with this. Forgive me, I'm certainly no expert when it comes to jQuery and Ajax. But I've made the change, but unfortunately it hasn't solved the problem. I just wondered whether you could possibly look at the page again please and let me know where I've gone wrong. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, I have updated my answer, You putted return false in switch block instead put it at the end see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Kundan Singh Chouhan. Thank you very much for this. I've made the change but unfortunately the problem hasn't been resolved. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, you have putted that state in wrong place it should in if block at the end, and you have putted it outside the event of submit.

Comment: Hi @Kunan Singh Chouhan, I'm really very sorry but could you possibly perhaps  put the whole of the revised code in your answer please, because I'm having trouble in understanding what I need to do. As I said earlier, my AJAX and jQuery knowledge isn't very good. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Kundan Singh Chouhan, sincere thank for the update and your continued help. I've made the changes you've suggested, but sadly the problem hasn't been resolved. I'm sure I'm being really dense here, but I think I've replicated your answer correctly. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, i checked and you have put the code correctly, it seems there is a problem with validation engine. I have updated my answer please try and let me know.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this, unfortunately the changes haven't solved the problem. I have run this through 'JavaScript' Console, and unfortunately there isn't any error shown. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Kundan Singh Chouhan, thank you very much for this and I really appreciate your continued help with this. Unfortunately I unable to get this to work. I'm very conscious of the amount of your time I've taken. So please don't spend anymore time on this. I think I need to go away and try and look at a different solution to try and resolve this. I do thank you so much for all your time, trouble and effort. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Kunden Singh Chouhan, thank your your reply. Sadly the solution didn't fix the problem. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, I checked your page and found you haven't putted the "return false" statement on correct place, it should be in the **onValidationComplete** event and you have putted it outside.

Comment: Hi @Kundan Singh Chouha, thank you very much for pointing this out. As I said in my initial post. I'm not very well versed with JavaScript. I've amended my page, to where I think it should be. If I've got this right, then unfortunately it hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: @IRHM, You have putted the wrong code, Use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tmNYw/) just paste this as it is and also remove the duplicate validation engine code that you have putted above the current code.

Comment: Hi Kundan Singh Chouhan, thank you very much for this. There is a slight change with the new code inserted. When I click the 'Save' button the message hangs on 'Please Wait'. I've run this through JS Console and the error is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I'm not sure whether this helps. Sincere thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, this issue is coming in the parseJson function, it seems that response is not returning in correct JSON format. So there is issue in the code of php file.

Comment: Hi thank you for this. I truly appreciate your help with this. I'll have to take a look at this to see if I can identify the problem. I'll have to get back to you on this if that's ok. Kind regards